# How are the steps to access GPIOs in linux kernel modules?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio

I am struggling to find out, what steps are necessary to access a gpio-pin from a linux kernel module.
Maybe someone can explain it to me by a simple example. I like to use pin 4(input) and 33(output). My steps so far:

1.) Device Tree(dts): I leave the dts file untouched - Do I need to setup the pin 4 and 33 via pin control?

2.) kernel module: some pseudo code

```
gpio_is_valid(4)
gpio_request_one(4, GPIOF_DIR_IN | GPIOF_EXPORT_DIR_FIXED , "myPin4")
gpio_export(4, false)
gpio_get_value(4)

gpio_is_valid(33)
gpio_request_one(33, GPIOF_DIR_OUT | GPIOF_INIT_LOW | GPIOF_OPEN_SOURCE | GPIOF_EXPORT_DIR_FIXED , "myPin33")
gpio_export(33, false)
gpio_set_value(33, 1)
```

How to do it in a proper way?

Comment: Study kernel **Documentation/gpio/***.

Comment: Adding to @sawdust follow [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/board.txt) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.txt), hope will help you

Comment: Choose names, describe them via Device Tree, get using `devm_gpiod_get()` and use GPIO descriptors (you are not suppose to export acquired pins, btw). @sawdust gave a starting point, though you may just check existing drivers.

Comment: let's try to formulate a tutorial together. I put an answer and everyone can change it, till we get to the point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest the combination of an own device tree file + a platform driver + character driver

**0.) RTF**

check how [device trees(dts)](http://devicetree.org/Device_Tree_Usage) are working

check how a [platform device](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt) works

check how a [character device](https://lwn.net/Articles/195805/) works

gain some knowledge about gpios and dts

[@gpio mappings](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/board.txt)

[@subsystems using gpios](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.txt)

[@Specifying GPIO information for devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt)

Read the informations provided by your SOC manufacturer.

The [state-of-the-art](http://elinux.org/images/9/9b/GPIO_for_Engineers_and_Makers.pdf) way to access the gpios is via `struct gpio_desc` variables. They are created form the device tree.

**1.) approach**

To toggle a pin under linux you need to make shure, that 3 units are working togehter.

The pin-controller(pinctrl) defines how the output is driven. Open source, pull up etc.

The pin-multiplexer(pinmux) defines different functions for the pin.

The gpio-controller(gpioctrl) translates the gpio number. p.E.: 44 -> GPIO A 11

These components are implemented by the SOC manufacturer. For each platform there are differences. An example for the SAMA5D35xxx follows.

@the device tree

Define the pin controller

```
pinctrl@fffff200 {
    pinctrl_myPins: myPins {
        atmel,pins = <AT91_PIOA 2 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_NONE  // pin 1
            AT91_PIOD 19 AT91_PERIPH_GPIO AT91_PINCTRL_NONE>; // pin 2
    };
};
```

Create a node witch is linked to the own platform device:

```
myPins {
    compatible = "myPlatformDevice";

    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_myPins>;

    pin1 = <&pioA 2 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    pin2 = <&pioD 19 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
};
```

@create platform + char driver (pseudo code):

```
// ----------------------
// kernel message support(via dmesg)
// ----------------------
#define KMSG_DEBUG(fmt,args...) printk(KERN_DEBUG "myDrv" ": "fmt"\n", ##args)
#define KMSG_PERR(fmt,args...) printk(KERN_ERR "myDrv" ": "fmt"\n", ##args)
#define KMSG_PINFO(fmt,args...) printk(KERN_INFO "myDrv" ": "fmt"\n", ##args)
// ----------------------
// trace support via defining dMyDrvTrace
// ----------------------
#ifndef dMyDrvTrace
    #define TRACE(...)
#else
    #define TRACE(fmt,args...) printk(KERN_INFO "myDrv" ": [%s] "fmt"\n", __FUNCTION__, ##args)
#endif


typedef struct SMyDrvDrvData {
    struct platform_device *pdev; //!< next device
    // here goes the local/private data
    int gpiod_pin1;
    int gpiod_pin2;

    u32 pin1;
    u32 pin2;
} TMyDrvDrvData;

static struct dentry * gmyPlattformDrvDebugfsRootDir; //!< root dir at debugfs

static int myPlattformDrv_probe(struct platform_device *pdev);
static int myPlattformDrv_remove(struct platform_device *pdev);

#if defined(CONFIG_OF)
    //! filter for the device tree class
    static struct of_device_id gMyPlattformDrvdtsFilter[] = {
        {.compatible = "myPlatformDevice"},
        {}
    };
    MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, gMyPlattformDrvdtsFilter);
#else
    #define gmyPlattformDrvdtsFilter (NULL)
#endif

static struct platform_device *MyPlattformDrv_devs[] = {
};

static struct platform_driver myPlattformDrv_driver = {
        .driver = {
            .name   = dMyPlattformDrvdriver,
            .owner  = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table =  of_match_ptr(gMyPlattformDrvdtsFilter),
        },
        .probe      = myPlattformDrv_probe,
        .remove     = myPlattformDrv_remove,
};


// char device

static dev_t gMyCharDev;
static struct class *gMyCharDevClass;
static struct cdev gMyCharDev_cdev;

static int dev_open      (struct inode *, struct file *);
static int dev_release   (struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dev_read  (struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t dev_write (struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

static const struct file_operations gMyCharDevOps =
{
    .read    = dev_read,
    .open    = dev_open,
    .write   = dev_write,
    .release = dev_release
};


//! looks up for the gpio name and request it
static int get_gpio(struct platform_device *pdev, const char * name, int * pGPIOnum)
{
    int n,i;
    int r;
    struct device_node * pDN;

    TRACE("look at %s for %s ...", pdev->name, name);
    // reset return value
    *pGPIOnum = 0;

    // parse device tree

    // get device tree entries associated with the device
    pDN = of_find_node_by_name(NULL, pdev->name);

    // parse pins
    n = of_gpio_named_count(pDN, name);
    if (n <= 0) {
        TRACE("no gpios found");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // get pin number
        *pGPIOnum = of_get_named_gpio(pDN,name, i);
        if (*pGPIOnum == -EPROBE_DEFER) {
            return r;
        }
        // check if pin number is valid
        if (gpio_is_valid(*pGPIOnum)) {
            // yes
            // request pin
            r = devm_gpio_request(&pdev->dev, *pGPIOnum, name);
            if (r) {
                return r;
            } else {
                r = gpio_direction_output(*pGPIOnum, 0);
                }
                if (r) return r;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//! probes the platform driver
static int myPlattformDrv_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct TMyDrvDrvData *priv;
    int i,j,r,gpioNum, ret;

    KMSG_PINFO("probe my driver ...");

    priv = kzalloc(sizeof(*priv), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!priv) {
        KMSG_PERR("Failed to allocate memory for the private data structure");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    priv->pdev = pdev;
    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, priv);

    TRACE("setup gpios ...");
    r = get_gpio(pdev, "pin1", &gpioNum);
    if (r) {
        KMSG_PERR("Failed to find gpio \"pin1\" in device tree");
    }
    // save number
    priv->gpiod_pin1 = gpioNum;

    // create "pin1" debugfs entry
    debugfs_create_u32("pin1", S_IRUGO, gmyPlattformDrvDebugfsRootDir, &priv->Pin1);

    r = get_gpio(pdev, "pin2", &gpioNum);
    if (r) {
        KMSG_PERR("Failed to find gpio \"pin2\" in device tree");
    }
    // save number
    priv->gpiod_pin2 = gpioNum;

    // create "pin2" debugfs entry
    debugfs_create_u32("pin1", S_IRUGO, gmyPlattformDrvDebugfsRootDir, &priv->Pin2);


    // create device class
    TRACE("create myCharDev char device class");

    // create char dev region
    ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&gMyCharDev, 0, 1, "myCharDev");
    if( ret < 0) {
        KMSG_PERR("alloc_chrdev_region error %i", ret);
        goto error;
    }

    // create device class
    if((gMyCharDevClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, dSEK4DevClass)) == NULL)
    {
        KMSG_PERR("class_create error");
        goto error_classCreate;
    }

    if(NULL == device_create(gMyCharDevClass, NULL, gMyCharDev, NULL, "myCharDev"))
    {
        KMSG_PERR("device_create error");
        goto error_deviceCreate;
    }

    cdev_init(&gMyCharDev_cdev, &gMyCharDevOps);
    ret = cdev_add(&gMyCharDev_cdev, gMyCharDev, 1);
    if(-1 == ret) {
        KMSG_PERR("cdev_add error %i", ret);
        goto error_device_add;
        return -1;
    }
    TRACE("added myCharDev char device");

    return 0;
// error handling block
error_std:
error_device_add:
    device_destroy(gMyCharDevClass, gMyCharDev);
error_deviceCreate:
    class_destroy(gMyCharDevClass);
error_classCreate:
    unregister_chrdev_region(gMyCharDev, 1);
error:
    return -1;
}
```